# Trigonometric identity equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation:

$$8\sin^2(x) + 6\cos^2(x) = 13\sin(2x)$$

I tried solving it, but the furthest I ever got was

$$4 - \cos^2(x) = 13\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

How can I solve this?

Comment: And yes, I tried using wolfram alpha, but the solution was 2 pages long, when this is a 10 minute problem according to my teacher.

Comment: One might observe that $4s^2-13sc+3c^2=(s-3c)(4s-c)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: You can try dividing with $\cos^2(x)$ to get a quadratic in $\tan(x)$.